# Why does my code not allow me to have empty cells with no fill

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set WF = Application.WorksheetFunction
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 6 Then
            'choose new color
            Target.Interior.Color = RGB( _
                WF.RandBetween(0, 255), _
                WF.RandBetween(0, 255), _
                WF.RandBetween(0, 255))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Currently it applies a random color in specific column whenever a change is applied to the cell(in said column). However, I want it to only assign a colour when there is text in the cell. If the text is deleted the cell contents should return to no fill. I've been trying to use target.interior.color = xlnone to accomplish this, but when I apply new conditions the eventhandler stops working.

Is there another way to approach this or better code i could use?

Also it may be worth adjusting the random colour range to avoid the possibility of black/white

Comment: Where's the code that sets the cell(s) to no fill?

Comment: I had tried X = 0 
If x > 0 then 
*insert code for random color* 
else target.interior.color = xlnone

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove fill from a cell then you can use `ColorIndex = xlNone`

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim WF, rng As Range
    Set WF = Application.WorksheetFunction
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 6 Then
            Set rng = Target.Resize(1, 5) '<<<< 5 cells wide
            If Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then
                rng.Interior.Color = RGB( _
                                        WF.RandBetween(20, 230), _
                                        WF.RandBetween(20, 230), _
                                        WF.RandBetween(20, 230))
            Else
                rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'clear any color
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

`WF.RandBetween(20, 230)` would prevent white/black fill

Comment: Thank you, this is the fix I was looking for. 
Hypothetically speaking, would there be a way to extend the colour to a range of columns in the row. e.g A1 is the target cell, but cells A1:S1 also are filled with the same colour 
Or this that too complex?

Comment: See edit above.  You can combine `Resize()` with `Offset()` if you want to shift the range left/right.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed the reply. Really appreciate your help with the solve for this. Works like a dream now